# How to start as an Android Developer Freelancer

Tags: android

I am thinking to get started as Freelance Android Developer. My questions are as follows: 
1. How do I get started as Android Developer?
2. How do I earn more profits while developing application in Android?
3. How should I win customers and make them come to me for more projects? 
4. What infrastructure is necessary for being a freelancer?

Please reply me. I require your help.

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to learn Java programming first, then you can start [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/basics/what-is-android.html).
2. A lot of things that depend on the situation.
3. Making solid interesting projects and giving good customer support.
4. Again, depends what you're up to.